# Google Cloud DNS nameserver Validity Issue

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, nameservers, google-cloud-dns

I have a problem with Cloud DNS. I just setted it up by following the Quickstart tutorial from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart).  But when I try to copy my name servers to register to my domain, it says  "**An error occurred. Please verify the validity of your nameservers and try again.**"

My domain resides in Hostgator.com. Kindly see the attached link below.

[image]

Thanks,
Alde

Comment: Please explain why you downvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself by just erasing the dot(.) in the last part in every nameserver.